# Ray Tracing vs Radiosity in Graphic

Tags: raytracing

I had an exam and there was a question which i couldn't answer..What kind of illumination phenomenon can not be implemented using ray tracing(Than radiosity is used in this case)

Answer (score 3):

Technically, path tracing (which is a kind of raytracing) implements the complete lighting equation. But they probably meant indirect lighting, iow. global illumination.